# Getting Exception in "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am building a signup page for my project in Netbeans. So I have added some images and icons which i have imported from the folders "AddNewBookIcons","adminIcons" and "icons". These folders are in my source package only and in the same directory as the main java class folder.

This is my folder structure inside source package:[folder str](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDHGN.png)

Sample code im using to path of the icon or image

```
jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

jLabel5.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/signup-library-icon.png"))); // NOI18N

jLabel5.setText("jLabel5");

jPanel1.add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(60, 140, 800, 420));
```

The image file is valid and it is inside the icons folder.
I have provided the write icons and image path also but still im getting this below error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at jframe.SignupPage.initComponents(SignupPage.java:141)
    at jframe.SignupPage.<init>(SignupPage.java:24)
    at jframe.SignupPage$4.run(SignupPage.java:373)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I was trying to solve it by taking help of some of the existing resources in internet but did not find any relevant details that solved my problem.

Expected: I am not able to find out why i am getting this exception even if i have provided the write image and icon path. Or is the path i have provided should be written in a different way? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the path is written wrong. You can write paths in java by using `\\` to go into a new folder in the path. You have to use two because just one of them is an escape character so if you put another, you escape the escape character and go back to normal. Instead of doing `"/icons/signup-library-icon.png"`, try doing `"\\icons\\signup-library-icon.png"`. If that doesn't work, try removing the two forward slashes in the start of the path.

Comment: I think both of them correct.  As for the first way, You need to add ".“ at first position. For example, "./icons/signup-library-icon.png".